# how to select 1 field and match with query from database

Tags: mongoose

im trying to find an object from an array of lowongan that match with the country and job title but this doesnt seem to work  and only bringing back some random _id

the schema is like this

```
employer schema = {
name : String,
lowongan : [object]
}



import Employer from "@/model/employer";
    import { connectToDB } from "@/utils/conectDb";

export default async function find(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      await connectToDB();
      const { job_title, country } = req.body;
      const { page } = req.query;
      const itemsPerPage = 10;
      const currentPage = parseInt(page) || 1;
      const limit = itemsPerPage * currentPage;

      const cari = await Employer.find(
        {},
        {
          lowongan: {
            $elemMatch: {
              job_title: job_title,
              country: country,
            },
          },
        },
        // Optional: Use projection to include only the matching "lowongan" objects
        { "lowongan.$": 1 }
      ).limit(limit);

      if (!cari || cari.length === 0) {
        // Handle case where no matching employers are found
        res.status(404).json({ message: "No matching employers found." });
        return;
      }

      res.status(200).json(cari);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ err: "Internal server error" });
    }
  }
}
```

i try using  but this doesnt work either

```
employer.find({},{
lowongan : 1 , job_title : job_title
})

but thats only bring the job_title no other  value
```

Answer (score 0):

well i choose the operator wrong elemMatch need tobe true both of its parameter

example
job : [{location : bali,visa : true } {location : jakarta,visa : false}]

if $elemMatch : location : bali ,visa : "" it return nothing
so i use $or and it solve problem